# F# : static let and static member

Tags: static, f#

I'm a noob in F# and currently reading Expert in F# 3.0.
Its the first compiled language I'm learning (I just know to program in R)

on chapter 6, p.117, we are introduced without much ceremony 
static let and static member. i don't really understand what it is

```
type Vector2D(dx : float, dy : float) =
     static let zero = Vector2D(0.0, 0.0)
     static let onex = Vector2D(1.0, 0.0)
     static let oney = Vector2D(0.0, 1.0)
     /// Get the zero vector
     static member Zero = zero
     /// Get a constant vector along the X axis of length one
     static member OneX = onex
     /// Get a constant vector along the Y axis of length one
     static member OneY = oney
```

There is no example who to proceed further in the book.

I'm typing this in F# interactive. From there, how do I construct a variable x whose value is zero (or onex...)?

I'm trying the following. Nothing works

```
let x = Zero;;
let y = Vector2D(2.0,2.0);; /// ok
y.Zero;;
stdin(237,1): error FS0809: Property 'Zero' is static
```

in http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/
there is this example,

```
type StaticExample() = 
    member this.InstanceValue = 1
    static member StaticValue = 2  // no "this"

// test
let instance = new StaticExample()
printf "%i" instance.InstanceValue
printf "%i" StaticExample.StaticValue
```

so i would have expected `y.Zero;;` to yield something above ?...

thanks. sorry the question is so basic. If someone can explain me what it is about...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the basic difference is that static members don't belong to an instance of a class.

rather than `y.Zero`, you get `Vector2D.Zero`.

To a first approximation you can think of these examples of properties of the type.

Comment: i should have read more carefully the book. it wasn't very well documented, but there was an example well hidden a few pages before.

Answer (score 1):

static members belong to the type on which they are declared and are accessed by the fully qualified type and member name. In this instance

```
let zero = Vector2D.Zero
let oneX = Vector2D.OneX
let oneY = Vector2D.OneY
```

The `Vector2D` type does not currently have any instance members, but if it did, these would be accessible on an instance of `Vector2D`

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the F# language guide's [`let` Bindings in Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/let-bindings-in-classes) article:

> A **`let` binding** in a class creates a *private* field or function;
> to expose data or functions publicly, declare a property or a member
> method.
>
> - An **instance `let` binding** is a `let` binding that is not preceded by the `static` keyword.
>
>   > Instance `let` bindings execute when objects are created.
> - **Static `let` bindings** are part of the static initializer for the class.
>
>   > Static `let` bindings are guaranteed to execute before the type is first used.

If one tried to refactor the `Vector2D` type by removing the `static` keywords before `zero`, `onex`, and `oney` private functions,

```ml
type Vector2D(dx : float, dy : float) =
     let zero = Vector2D(0.0, 0.0)
     let onex = Vector2D(1.0, 0.0)
     let oney = Vector2D(0.0, 1.0)
     /// Get the zero vector
     static member Zero = zero
     /// Get a constant vector along the X axis of length one
     static member OneX = onex
     /// Get a constant vector along the Y axis of length one
     static member OneY = oney
```

then they would have received

```
error FS0039: The value or constructor 'zero' is not defined.
```

as `zero` and co. are only guaranteed to evaluate when the class is instantiated.